# Bootstrap active tab doesn't move to top of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, tabs

I have a tab system using Bootstrap 2.3.2 based on the tutorial here: http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/319_bootstrap_pills_tabs/Tabs-Pills-BEGIN/tabs-pills.html

My nav list is fixed on the page and clicking each link opens the information inside its tab.

My issue is that the content in each tab is quite long and requires scrolling. If halfway down the list you click one of the other nav links it changes to the new tab but still leaves you halfway down the page. The behaviour should be to head to the start of the active tab. ie. moving the page to the top of the new active tab.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-stacked">
<div class="tabbable tabs-left ">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span2 sidebar-nav-fixed" id="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabs2-pane1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2-pane2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2-pane3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content span10 offset2 middle-bar-information">
        <div id="tabs2-pane1" class="tab-pane active">
            <p class="header">TEST TEST TEST
            </p>
            <br><br>
        </div><!-- End tabs2-pane1 -->
        <div id="tabs2-pane2" class="tab-pane">
            <p class="header">Okay. Now... Hardened Kevlar plates over titanium-dipped, tri-weave fibers for flexibility. </p>
        </div><!-- End tabs2-pane2 -->
    </div><!-- End tab-content -->
</div><!-- End tabbable -->
```

You can test it here: http://bootply.com/80587

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2, am loading bootstrap.min.js which include bootstrap-tab.js. The tabs work fine and activate other than not moving to the top of the tab content.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
$('#tabs-stacked li').click( function(){
var tabs_offset = $('#tabs-stacked').offset();
scrollTo(tabs_offset.left, tabs_offset.top);
});
```

It works - not pretty - but it works.